# what permission should I use to receiver of android notitications?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-permissions

I want to be notified when use click a notification.
The want I am doing it now is

```
notification.contentIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,intent, 0);

<receiver
    android:name=".notificationsClickReceiver">
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="com.example.android.notification.CLICK" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Everything works. However, I got a warning "Exported receiver does not require 
 permission" Which means every app can send the broadcast to my app. What permission should I add so only system notification tray is allowed to send the broadcast ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add [`android:exported="false"`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html) to the `<receiver ...>` tag. This prevents your receiver from being accessed by other apps.

Comment: As in the notification pull-down? No, that's baked into the OS.

Comment: Correct. It just prevents it from being exported to other apps that have been installed on the device.